# PHPMailer connection issues

Tags: php, windows, xampp, phpmailer

I want to send a email using php(using windows operating system).However I keep encountering connection issue and that the attachments file are not found.Are there any solutions?

```
//-------------sending mail----------------------------

//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace

//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

//Create an instance; passing true enables exceptions

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings

    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'username@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'password';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('hotelpage@gmail.com', 'Hotels Page');
    $mail->addAddress('MohanDepesh@gmail.com', 'MohanDepesh');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@gmail.com', 'no-reply');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
 catch (Exception $e) {

    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";

}
```

[image: Issue encountered (image)]

Comment: Did you configure sending mails through SMTP within gmail? You need to enable a setting to allow sending mail.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en . You need to configure an App Password for your Google Account and use that in your PHP code as the gmail password.

Comment: Also why are you setting a "no-reply" address in the reply-to field? That makes no sense. And Gmail is unlikely to let you send a message from an account which isn't the one you're authenticating with. It's not intended to be like an all-purpose SMTP server.

Comment: It's always a good idea to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps) before posting.

Answer (score -1):

Please check following points of you are receiving errors-

1.Check if you are using correct mail and password.
2. There maybe an issue due to "Allow less secure apps" settings.Try to turn on this setting for testing.
Please attach exact error if you are still facing issue.

Edit: As Allow less secure apps is disable now , you can use appPassword for it

Comment: That setting no longer exists.

Comment: Indeed that setting no longer exist from [May 30, 2022](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz yeah i read it.Then we need to have a appPassword for it

Comment: Yes, only after having activated the 2FA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).